# Transform List to Tensor more accurat

Tags: list, transform, pytorch, tensor

I want to return in the Dataloader a list. 
But to return it, its need to be a tensor right? 
So I transform it but in this process information is lost, is there another way to do this?

```
pt_tensor_from_list = torch.tensor(pose_transform)
pt_tensor_from_list = torch.FloatTensor(pose_transform)
```

I excpect the output:

> ([[-0.0003000000142492354, -0.0008999999845400453,
>   0.00039999998989515007, 0], [0.0010000000474974513, -0.00019999999494757503, 0.0003000000142492354, 0], [0.00019999999494757503, -0.0005000000237487257,
>   -0.0008999999845400453, 0], [5.484399795532227, -24.28619956970215, 117.5000991821289, 1])

But it is:

> ([[ -0.0003, -0.0009, 0.0004, 0.0000],
>       [ 0.0010, -0.0002, 0.0003, 0.0000],
>       [ 0.0002, -0.0005, -0.0009, 0.0000],
>       [ 5.4844, -24.2862, 117.5001, 1.0000]])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not losing any information during such conversion. The reason why it looks like that, more compactly, is as when you are printing a tensor, it invokes `__str__()` or `__repr__()` methods and it makes your tensor looks more pretty. As you can find [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/09f22d10a695bfba8ffb3327b9920fd3358c00ee/torch/tensor.py#L66-L77) `torch.Tensor` uses a kind of internal tensor formatter called `_tensor_str`. If you look inside the code [link](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/17268a92253f46e67f8c8b233c937bdb828540dd/torch/_tensor_str.py) you will find that by default parameter `precision` is set to 4:

> precision: Number of digits of precision for floating point output          (default = 4).

That's why you have only 4 digits for tensor values when printing the tensor. But actually, values stored in a tensor are the same as in original list.

Here is small example to get an idea:

Code:

```py
import torch

test_list = ([[-0.0003000000142492354, -0.0008999999845400453, 0.00039999998989515007, 0],
              [0.0010000000474974513, -0.00019999999494757503, 0.0003000000142492354, 0],
              [0.00019999999494757503, -0.0005000000237487257, -0.0008999999845400453, 0],
              [5.484399795532227, -24.28619956970215, 117.5000991821289, 1]])

print('Original values:')
for i in test_list:
    for j in i:
        print(j)

pt_tensor_from_list = torch.FloatTensor(test_list)

print('When printing FloatTensor:')
print(pt_tensor_from_list.dtype, pt_tensor_from_list, sep='\n')

print('When printing each value separately:')
for i in pt_tensor_from_list:
    for j in i:
        print(j.item())
```

Output:

```py
Original values:
-0.0003000000142492354
-0.0008999999845400453
0.00039999998989515007
0
0.0010000000474974513
-0.00019999999494757503
0.0003000000142492354
0
0.00019999999494757503
-0.0005000000237487257
-0.0008999999845400453
0
5.484399795532227
-24.28619956970215
117.5000991821289
1
When printing FloatTensor:
torch.float32
tensor([[-3.0000e-04, -9.0000e-04,  4.0000e-04,  0.0000e+00],
        [ 1.0000e-03, -2.0000e-04,  3.0000e-04,  0.0000e+00],
        [ 2.0000e-04, -5.0000e-04, -9.0000e-04,  0.0000e+00],
        [ 5.4844e+00, -2.4286e+01,  1.1750e+02,  1.0000e+00]])
When printing each value separately:
-0.0003000000142492354
-0.0008999999845400453
0.00039999998989515007
0.0
0.0010000000474974513
-0.00019999999494757503
0.0003000000142492354
0.0
0.00019999999494757503
-0.0005000000237487257
-0.0008999999845400453
0.0
5.484399795532227
-24.28619956970215
117.5000991821289
1.0
```

As you can see, we are getting the same values when printing each value separately.

**BUT** you can lose some info if you choose the wrong tensor types, for example `HalfTensor` instead of `FloatTensor`. Here is an example:

Code:

```py
pt_tensor_from_list = torch.HalfTensor(test_list)

print('When printing HalfTensor:')
print(pt_tensor_from_list.dtype, pt_tensor_from_list, sep='\n')

print('When printing each value separately:')
for i in pt_tensor_from_list:
    for j in i:
        print(j.item())
```

Output:

```py
When printing HalfTensor:
torch.float16
tensor([[-2.9993e-04, -8.9979e-04,  4.0007e-04,  0.0000e+00],
        [ 1.0004e-03, -2.0003e-04,  2.9993e-04,  0.0000e+00],
        [ 2.0003e-04, -5.0020e-04, -8.9979e-04,  0.0000e+00],
        [ 5.4844e+00, -2.4281e+01,  1.1750e+02,  1.0000e+00]],
       dtype=torch.float16)
When printing each value separately:
-0.0002999305725097656
-0.0008997917175292969
0.0004000663757324219
0.0
0.0010004043579101562
-0.00020003318786621094
0.0002999305725097656
0.0
0.00020003318786621094
-0.0005002021789550781
-0.0008997917175292969
0.0
5.484375
-24.28125
117.5
1.0
```

As you can notice now the values are (a little bit) different. Visit [pytorch tensor docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html) to learn more about different types of `torch.tensor`.